# Python threads using multiple CPUs

Tags: python, multithreading

I have this python code which implements threading. When I examine the cpu usage by this process, it seems like it uses all the CPUs which shouldn't be the case due to GIL.

```
import threading
def counter(n):
    for i in range(0,n):
        i = i+1
t1 = threading.Thread(target = counter, args = (30000000,))
t2 = threading.Thread(target = counter, args = (30000000,))
t3 = threading.Thread(target = counter, args = (30000000,))
t4 = threading.Thread(target = counter, args = (30000000,))
t1.start();t2.start();t3.start();t4.start()
t1.join();t2.join();t3.join();t4.join()
```

The cpu usage stats :

```
bash@bash:~$ ps -p 3298 -L -o pid,tid,psr,pcpu
 PID   TID PSR %CPU
 3298  3298   0  0.1
 3298  3299   2 39.8
 3298  3300   3 44.8
 3298  3301   1 45.8
 3298  3302   0 50.0
```

Can some one explain what's happening??
The output of`lscpu` command if needed..

```
bash@bash:~$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 69
Stepping:              1
CPU MHz:               1700.156
BogoMIPS:              4788.99
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              3072K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
```

Comment: There's nothing stopping it from using all the CPUs concurrently, just not parallelly.

Comment: You've got 2 cores, which are hyperthreading, both of them are 50 % utilized.

Comment: What I understand from concurrency and parallelism is that :
After a thread(say being run by cpu1) releases gil the next thread can be                  run by cpu2(say) but two CPUs can't work simultaneously at a given point of time......Am I right!!

Comment: Pretty much. 2 or more cores cannot interpret python simultaneously, so mostly what you wrote. There are many good posts about this here that explain different aspects of the subject. For example why C-extensions can "avoid" the limitations of GIL in some cases etc.

Comment: Another doubt struck my mind....!! I understand concurrency and parallelism now but doesn't `ps` command list the stats of cpu usage at a "given point of time." So, shouldn't it show only one cpu that is being used??

Comment: Strictly speaking with that definition the usage will always be either 100% or 0%, either working or not. `ps` et al. display usage sampled over some period of time. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58539/top-and-ps-not-showing-the-same-cpu-result for a more detailed explanation.